# SQL Server View with a Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have an extremely complex view that returns 5 columns in SQL Server, If I query the view with `SELECT * FROM PR_MASTER_VIEW` I get all of the results I expect to see. However if I add a simple `WHERE` to the view I no longer get the expected results. For Example,

```
  SELECT * FROM PR_MASTER_VIEW returns;

BL_ID|  M_DATE  |  BFH | SEQ|MT_ID
------------------------------------
   20|2015-01-01| 435.0| 402|0
   20|2014-01-02| 835.2| 403|0
   20|2013-02-03| 335.3| 404|0
   20|2012-06-04| 423.4| 405|0
   20|2011-04-09| 135.8| 406|0
```

Adding a Where to filter on `BL_ID=20` however returns this

```
SELECT * FROM PR_MASTER_VIEW WHERE BL_ID=20 returns;

BL_ID|  M_DATE  |  BFH | SEQ|MT_ID
------------------------------------
   20|2015-01-01| 435.0| 402|0
   20|2014-01-02| 835.2| 403|0
   20|2011-04-09| 135.8| 406|0
```

Any Ideas as as to why I am not seeing the expected results?
I have already run a `SELECT DISTINCT BL_ID FROM PR_MASTER_VIEW` and it only returns one record of 20

(UPDATE)

```
 create view PR_MASTER_VIEW as select bl_id, m_date, bfh, seq, mt_id  
 from PRM_SI_VIEW where d in ( select min (d) from PRM_SI_VIEW group by  bl_id, m_date, bfh, seq )
```

Comment: Impossible to replicate @JohnHC there is something we aren't being told.

Comment: The SELECT * returns 5 results adding the Where makes it return 3

Comment: Can you add your view's code?

Comment: I think this would be a lot easier to debunk if we could see the code for the view as well.

Comment: Does the column name 'BL_ID' does really exist or is at an alias name ?

Comment: Im sure adding the code for the view would help, but its well over 1000 lines of SQL, is there  a way to determine the execution path so I can debug?

Comment: @James: Maybe a complete overhaul of the database structure would help you more... 1000 lines of SQL seems a bit much for only 5 columns. :)

Comment: @waka I would agree, I didn't write this, just need to fix what I have

Comment: Data type of `BL_ID`?  Is the value on the rows that disappear something like `' 20'`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I'd like to see how it could be that long.  Could you post the basic structure of it?  Leave out the columns but give us the meat of the view, is it one large select?  Is it unions?  CTEs? something else?  At first glance views can't do what you've described because they don't act on the where clause, Sql does.

Comment: Just to avoid something stupid that I've seen with views - drop and re-create the view so that SQL Server will recompile it.

Comment: This is going to take a bit but I will rebuild all the views and if I can ill post the basic structure, itll take some time

Comment: @James - is that a typo in your comment, several typos in the original question, or did you comment with the datatype of the wrong column?  In your queries you refer to `BL_ID` not `BT_ID`.  Also it may matter: how are you determining the column's data type?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger my mistake BL_ID is an INT Data type, typo in the comment, the datatype is set in a table buried under a pile of views, its just passed up to the view